# Finding $F(x)$ from $F(kx),$ where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of the function $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I have that $F(e^{x}x) = e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1$, and I would like to find $F(x)$.

**Attempt**

Since $F(e^{x}x) = e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1,$ $F(t) = \alpha_{1}t^{\beta_{1}} + \alpha_{2}t^{\beta_{2}} + \alpha_{3}t^{\beta_{3}} + \alpha_{4}t^{\beta_{4}}.$

Let $t = e^{x}x,$ which means that $F(t) = \alpha_{1}(e^{x}x)^{\beta_{1}} + \alpha_{2}(e^{x}x)^{\beta_{2}} + \alpha_{3}(e^{x}x)^{\beta_{3}} + \alpha_{4}(e^{x}x)^{\beta_{4}} = e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1.$

Therefore, $\alpha_{2} = -1, \alpha_{4} = -1, \beta_{2} = 1,$ and $\beta_{4} = 0.$

$F(t) = \alpha_{1}t^{\beta_{1}} - t + \alpha_{3}t^{\beta_{3}} - 1 = e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1.$

Comment: Use integration by part for each of $e^xx^2$ and $e^xx$

Comment: @Chuks I do not understand how this will help. Could you explain, please? :-)

Comment: OK...am typing up the answer...u will see it soon.

Comment: @Chuks Okay, thank you very much! :-D

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask here. Your function is already a function of x, since $e^x$ is itself a function of x. Then F(x) simply equals $e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1$

Comment: @Sidd Well, no. If $F(e^{x}x) = e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1,$ $F(x) \neq e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1,$ is it? That is like saying, let $F(x) = \frac{1}{3} x^{3},$ then $F(3x) = \frac{1}{3} x^{3}$ too, which is clearly a false statement.

Comment: I think you are getting confused between passing $3x$ as the argument, and $F$ being a function of $3x$.

Comment: @Sidd No, I can assure you that I am not.

Comment: You can write $F(x)$ in terms of the Lambert W Function.

Comment: If you are trying to find $\alpha_3$ and $\beta_3$ such that $\alpha_3t^{\beta_3} = e^x$, then that won't be possible, since they are both linearly independent for all scalar values of $\alpha_3$ and $\beta_3$. And since using *1* as the proportionality constant gives back the original equality, hence the equality won't be possible.

Comment: @Sidd Ah, I see.

Comment: Yes, @Dr.MV! It would be $\int_{0}^{y} W(y) \,dy, y = e^{x}x,$ wouldn't it?

Comment: @Taylor And thus, $f(x)=W(x)$!  That is, $F(x)$ is the integral of the Lambert W and the $-1$ is simply a constant of integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I can understand your question. I hope my answer will help you. We can rephrase your question in the following way:

> Let $F$ be a function such that $F(e^{x}x) = e^{x}x^{2} - e^{x}x + e^{x} - 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. What is the expression of $F$?

We can start by considering the map $x \mapsto y=x e^x$:
[image]

As you can see, your "defining" relation is ambiguous for $x \leq 0$, since as $x \leq 0$, $y$ ranges only from a negative value to $0$, and to each admissible $y$ we associate two distinct values of $x$. The situation is easier if $x>-e^{-1}$, since $x \mapsto x e^x$ is strictly increasing and hence bijective. If $g$ is the inverse of $x \in [-e^{-1},+\infty) \mapsto x e^x$, then 
$$
F(x)=e^{g(x)} g(x)^2 -e^{g(x)}g(x)+e^{g(x)}-1.
$$
Since a closed formula for $g$ is unknown, I doubt this answer will be what you expected.

To summarize: your identity defines a function $F \colon [-e^{-1},+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ in an implicit way. For negative values of $x$ you are in the same situation as this example: given that $G(x^2)= \sin x$, find $G$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Siminore. To be honest, I was not sure as to whether or not a closed-form could be reached, but, I did know that the function $F(x)$ is the integral of the Lambert W function, which, of course, has no closed-form formula either.

I am very grateful for your help, and for the time that you have taken to construct such a fabulous answer.

Comment: If I might add, if you differentiate expression for $F(xe^x)$ and play a bit, you can get $f(xe^x) = x$ on $[0,+\infty\rangle$, so $F(x) = \int_a^x g^{-1}(t)\ dt$ where $g(x) = xe^x$.

Comment: @Siminore Actually, there is.  It is The Lambert W Function.

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, any existing function is a closed formula of itself... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's summarize the comments in an answer. Differentiating expression for $F(xe^x)$ we get $$(e^x+xe^x)f(xe^x) = x(e^x + xe^x)$$ and thus, for $x\neq -1$ we have $$f(xe^x) = x \implies f(x) = W(x)$$ and consequently, $$F(x) = \displaystyle\int_a^x W(t)\ dt$$ Now, to determine $a$: 
$$\begin{align*}
F(xe^x) &= \displaystyle\int_a^{xe^x} W(t)\ dt \\
&= \left[ t = ue^u,\ dt = (u+1)e^u \right] \\
&= \displaystyle\int_{W(a)}^x u(u+1)e^u\ du\\
&= (x^2 - x + 1)e^x - (W(a)^2 - W(a) + 1)e^{W(a)} \implies W(a) = 0 \implies a = 0
\end{align*}$$ so, $$F(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^x W(t)\ dt$$

Comment: Well done! A +1